# How can I extract the value inside the curly brackets in python beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[HTML excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tj8m.png)

This is my code so far:

```
s = BS(r.content, 'lxml')
findDiv = s.find('div', {'id':'BodyContentPlaceholder_T00DF23F8005_Col00'})
findTable = findDiv.findAll('table', {'style':'width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;'})

for table in findTable:
        rows = table.findAll('tr')
        rows = rows[1:]
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.findAll('td')
            extension = cells[3].button.input.text
            print('docs page ' + str(extension))
            #extention = re.compile(pattern, text)
            docpage_url_ending = cells[3].find('value')
            print('url ' + str(docpage_url_ending))
```

I'm trying to get navigateUrl text from this

```
<input id="ctl00_BodyContentPlaceholder_C013_RadListView1_ctrl1_rlb1_ClientState" name="ctl00_BodyContentPlaceholder_C013_RadListView1_ctrl1_rlb1_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Documents&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;navigateUrl&quot;:&quot;/procurement/procurement-bids/constructionprocurementdetail?Title=Lakeland Adult Daycare Center Roof Replacement 18-785&quot;,&quot;primary&quot;:false}">
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json
import bs4
import urllib

data = '<input id="ctl00_BodyContentPlaceholder_C013_RadListView1_ctrl1_rlb1_ClientState" name="ctl00_BodyContentPlaceholder_C013_RadListView1_ctrl1_rlb1_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Documents&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;navigateUrl&quot;:&quot;/procurement/procurement-bids/constructionprocurementdetail?Title=Lakeland Adult Daycare Center Roof Replacement 18-785&quot;,&quot;primary&quot;:false}">'

# cook up some soup
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
# extract the relevant attribute
vals_as_string = soup.html.body.input.attrs['value']
# it's urlencoded, so decode it
unquoted_vals_as_string = urllib.parse.unquote(vals_as_string)
# turns out, it's json
vals_as_json = json.loads(unquoted_vals_as_string)
# well, json converts to dict, so there's our target
navigateUrl = vals_as_json['navigateUrl']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you get to your `navigateUrl`:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

s = BS(r.content, 'lxml')
findDiv = s.find('div', {'id':'BodyContentPlaceholder_T00DF23F8005_Col00'})
findTable = findDiv.findAll('table', {'style':'width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;'})

for table in findTable:
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    rows = rows[1:]
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.findAll('td')
        extension = cells[3].button.input.text
        print('docs page ' + str(extension))
        #extention = re.compile(pattern, text)
        docpage_url_ending = json.loads(cells[3].button.input.attr['value'])['navigateUrl']
        print('url ' + docpage_url_ending)
```

Comment: i'm getting this error when i try your code TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please tell us which part exactly you want to extract and give a bit more context around your `input` HTML.

Comment: I want to extract this part:                                               /procurement/procurement-bids/constructionprocurementdetail?Title=Lakeland Adult Daycare Center Roof Replacement 18-785

Comment: I agree (to a certain extent). Didn't notice that *value* contains a JSON object. It was long day for me :D But since we're not parsing whole websites here this wouldn't do any harm, as long as it's not going too far.

Comment: @JosefAssad Updated mine to a one line version but to be fair I upvoted your's, since you were the first to come up with a clean solution :)

Comment: it still not working, im getting this error    navigateUrl = json.loads(urllib.parse.unquote(cells[3].attrs["value"]))["navigateUrl"]
KeyError: 'value'

Comment: also, i forgot to mention that when i do a print on input, the value doesn't display, meaning everything inside the curly brackets including the navigate Url

Comment: You get this error probably because `cells` contains a list of *<td>* tags and I heavily doubt that those tags contain a *value* attribute. Please provide us more of your HTML data so that we don't have to guess what it really looks like.

Comment: yes it contains a list, and the navigate url is in cells[3], i uploaded a more detail html image

Comment: See my updated answer. You're using the `find` command on the wrong object.